# how to write inline if || if in angular

Tags: json, angular, angular-reactive-forms

i want to patch a value to formControl but i need to check whether it meet the requirement or not.

```
  addCard(sectionItems?: any) {
    let itemControl = this.fb.group({
      'name': [sectionItems ? sectionItems.name : '', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      'code': [sectionItems ? sectionItems.code : '', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      'url': [sectionItems ? sectionItems.url : '', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      'materialSlug': [sectionItems ?  sectionItems.material.slug : null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      'description': [sectionItems ? sectionItems.description : '', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      'options': this.fb.array([])
    });
    (<FormArray>this.editSectionForm.get('formItems')).push(itemControl);
  }
```

this function will create forms dynamically, and also can create blank form if `sectionItems`, but on `materialSlug` i need to check if `sectionItems == 'material'` how can i achieve that?

i've tried changing `sectionItems ?  sectionItems.material.slug` to `sectionItems.type ?  sectionItems.material.slug` but it won't work if i want to add blank form which doesn't have `type` property

Comment: `'materialSlug': [sectionItems?.material?.slug || null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],` Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

How about the [optional chaining operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) (sometimes called elvis operator)

```
sectionItems?.type ? sectionItems.material.slug : null
```

Comment: i've said it on my post that it's not working cause i need to add new blank card which doesn't have property type

Comment: Sounds like I'm missing something. But if `sectionItems` is null then `sectionItems?.type` will return `undefined` which seems to be what you need?

Compare the results with and without the ?.operator here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/DYUwLgBAlgdgbgQ2FAJgFQBawOYC4IIwCeEAvBDAK7DADcAsAFBMDGA9jAM5ugB0KIAEaVsACliJk6LDGwB+XmCIAHEAEoGzRuy48Q-ISPHwkqTDkUr1tIA

Comment: yes i've tried it but i'll try again later and let you know

Comment: so yes type return undefined, and i can't make new card, how can i make blank card?

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost now. Suggest you edit the original question to make it clearer what you are trying to do.

Comment: i already fix it, actually the error is not from `sectionItems.type` but in my html

Answer (score 0):

Use simple ternary operator like

```
sectionItems && sectionItems.material ? sectionItems.material.slug : null
```

Comment: can it be like `sectionItems && sectionItems.material != null ? sectionItems.material.slug : null` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
'materialSlug': [ (sectionItems && sectionItems == 'material') ?  sectionItems.material.slug : null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
```

Comment: i think it's simillar to the first answer, but `sectionItems == 'material'` i'm not sure if it's truthy cause `sectionItems` is an array